# How do i copy an object of a class in another class

Tags: c++, oop

I have class A and class B, and I created in class B object class A.
My question is how to copy object class A in class B by using instructor copy?

```
class B {
    A *obj;
    unsigned short room;
    unsigned short area;
public:
    B();
    B(const B&);
    ~B();
    void setRoom(unsigned short);
    void setArea(unsigned short);
    unsigned short getRoom() { return room; };
    unsigned short getArea() { return area; };
};
```

And here is instructor copy:

```
B::B(const B&p)
{
    room = p.room;
    area = p.area;
    // A = ?!
}
```

Another question: How to set and get object A in class B?

```
//void setObj(A*);?
// A* getObj():?
```

Thanks

Comment: You did not "create in class B object class A". The only thing that class A contains is a pointer to an indeterminate number of instances of class B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `A` has a copy constructor, you can just do:

```
B::B(const B& p)
{
    room = p.room;
    area = p.area;
    obj = new A(*(p.obj));
}
```

Preferably:

```
B::B(const B& p) : 
    obj(new A(*(p.obj))), room(p.room), area(p.area)
{ }
```

And I hope your destructor `~B();` deletes `obj`?

```
B::~B()
{
    delete obj;
}
```

Read up on [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) And [Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

Answer (score 1):

```
How to set and get object A in class B?
```

Set the object by using the following format.

```
void B::setAObj(A *aobj)
{
obj = aobj;
}
```

get the object by using the following

```
A* B::getAobj()
{
return obj;
}
```